# Count files recursively in several paths, with exclusions and eliminating redundant files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, count, duplicates

I am trying to create a set of instructions in Powershell on how to:

1. Retrieve files from several non related folders and count them, with exceptions of certain files and/or subfolders implemented
2. Give me the last modified file (most recent)
3. Remove duplicate files based on name, date-time, and filesize, and not just name (same name but different files can be in several folders), because the file could be repeated in the backup parameters as redundant file wildcard/folders, which will mean the exact same file in same path can be counted twice or more, and then ruin my file count.

What I have done so far (example of a browser profile path, after I enter it):

**(The "arrows" are pointing to the various parameters)**

```
       File           File          folder     many JSON inside folder    Folder
        |              |               |                    |              |
        v              v               v                    v              v
```

`GCI bookmarks, 'Current Session', databases\*, extensions\manifest.json, 'Local Storage\*' -Recurse   |  ? { $_.FullName -inotmatch 'Local Storage\\http* | Databases\\http*'}   | Get-Unique | measure-object -line`

```
                                                  ^                       ^
                                                  |                       |
       EXCLUSIONS:           HTTP* files inside folder      HTTP* subfolders inside folder
```

This already filters all the files I want from the ones I don't want, count them, and remove duplicates, BUT: also removes many Json files with the same name inside different folders, without taking into account file size (though I think it still differentiates dates)

Bottomline what I want is that capability of command line RAR and 7Zip, to know **exactly** what to include in the archive: We give an input of files and folders, we may by mistake include a subfolder already covered by a previous wild card, we program exceptions (*-x!* in case of 7zip), and the program knows **exactly** what files to include and exclude, and **without** compressing the same file twice

This is so I can know if a new backup is necessary or not, relatively to the previous one (different number of files, or most recently modified file). I know about the "update" function on rar and 7zip, but it's not what I want.
Speaking about the most recently written file, is there a way of some sort of "parallel piping"?  A recursive file search that can output the results to 2 commands down the chain, instead of doing a (long) scan for the file count, and repeating the scan to find the most recent file?

What I mean is:

```
         **THIS:                                        **Instead of THIS:

          _______ >FILE COUNT
         |
  SCAN --+                                   SCAN -->FILE COUNT ;  SCAN -->MOST RECENT FILE
         |_______ >MOST RECENT FILE
```

I've done almost all the work, but I hit a wall. All I'm missing is the removal of redundant files (e.g. same exact file in the same path being counted twice or more due to redundant parameters entered, though I want same name files in differents folders to still be counted); and while at it I wouldn't mind to get the last modified file also, so I don't have to repeat the same scan again (powershell can be very slow sometimes). 
This last point is less important but it would be nice if it worked though.

Any help you can give me on htis would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for reading :-)

Comment: The -(i)notmatch operator is RegEx based, to match any number of any chars use `.*`, so no wildcard `*` here. Also the spaces around the alternation `|` would be literal  and here obviously wrong. IMO you want to catch too much things with one ommand.

Comment: Isn't `.*` for file/folder extensions?
As for the spaces around the pipe, I actually didn't put them in my original code, only here for visual clarification, but I didn't know they would be treated literally. I didn't originally even put spaces near the ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something along the lines of

```
#generate an example list with the exact same files listed more than once, and possibly files by the same name in sub-folders
$lst = ls -file; $lst += ls -file -recurse

$UniqueFiles = ($lst | sort -Property FullName -Unique)      #remove exact dupes
$UniqueFiles = ($UniqueFiles| sort -Property Directory,Name) #make it look like ls again

# or most recent file per filename
$MostRecent = ($lst | sort -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | group -Property Name | %{$_.group[0]})
```

Although I don't understand how the file size plays in unless you're looking for files with the same size and name to only be listed once regardless of where it lives in the folder tree. In which case you may want to group by hash value so even if it has a different name it'll still be listed only once.

```
$MostRecentSameSize = ($lst | sort -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | group -Property @{exp='Name'},@{exp='Length'} | %{$_.group[0]})

# or by hash
$MostRecentByHash = ($lst | sort -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | group -Property @{exp={(Get-FileHash $_ -a md5).hash}} | %{$_.group[0]})
```

Comment: You're right, the size and date (+time) was meant to (almost) garantee the file is the same without hashing every single file, or the scan would be really long and stressful to the disk. But anyway it's silly, because it could make sense for the exact same file to be in different folders, like *INI* or *.nomedia* files (it was late, lol)
What it should really be done is removing duplicate files with the same name **AND** path, like this dummy output from *GCI:* 

`2 Example_file.txt    {C:\Documents\Example.txt,C:\Documents\Example.txt,X:\TEXTES\Example.txt} `

2 duplicates but 1 is not

Comment: I'll try in a while your code, thanks both of you so far

Comment: @PedroCoimbra, from your first comment I believe the first one `$UniqueFiles` is the one you're looking for. Also I'm not too sure how often you're planning on running it, but I used the MD5 hash because it's fast and doesn't have multiple passes so it shouldn't cause too much wear and tear, you could also reduce the over head by substituting `$UniqueFiles` for `$lst` in the `$MostRecentByHash` calculation to only compute the hash once per file.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Gregor y
I've found out that the `| sort -Property Directory`  keeps same name files in different folders -good, if they're there it's suppose to be that way-, but unfortunately it also repeatedly counts the same files in the same folders if there are redundancy wildcards in the search parameters.

`| sort -unique | sort -Property Directory` is the opposite, it removes repetitions of the same files (with same path) asked more than once (cool, I only want one instance), but unfortunately also filters out files with the same name (equal or not) in different folders.

Comment: Is it possible for a switch/option that filters out duplicates of files with the same names **and** paths, and leaves everything else?
Like `ls *.txt, SUBfolder\*.txt, 111.*`  inside a fictious working folder should bring:  
`  `
`111.txt
222.txt
SUBfolder\111.txt
SUBfolder\readme.txt
SUBfolder\ANOTHER.txt`   
    
Istead of :   
    
`111.txt
222.txt
SUBfolder\111.txt
SUBfolder\readme.txt
SUBfolder\ANOTHER.txt
111.txt
222.txt`  
   
Notice the duplicate 111 and 22 at the end because of the redundant search parameters. Those are tho ones I want to eliminate

Comment: (no line feeds in comments? Seriously?? yeah, because command outputs don't suck that way or anything...)

Comment: @PedroCoimbra I essentially did a `| sort -property fullname -unique`, because the full name has the path and the file name, then i resorted those results by directory because it looks nicer that way. However now that I think about it a little more, if you have both a mapped drive and a UNC path then the same file could still potentially be listed twice.

Comment: I think you got it!! :D The `| sort -property fullname -unique` works, finally it does what I want, counts everything except repeated file mentions. I didn't want the hash method because depending on the file nature, number of files and number of backups, it would be far too overkill.
Thanks again @Gregor  :-)